Azure Portal: Check available disk space for Managed Disks
We have close to 20 subscriptions of Azure, How can I check the disk usage (free space) we have on all disks in Azure Portal? In the disk view I cannot find the column disk usage / space. We have both attached and unattached disks so we want to check on the usage. Is there any PS script for this?

Have you tried any code to check the available disk space for Managed Disks?

Hi @VenkatV, the code is based off VMs the command .StorageProfile.OsDisk & .StorageProfile.DataDisks. What I need is a list of all disks across my subscriptions and find out the availability

Are you looking for only a PowerShell script or any query, like a KQL query?

If it's a PS Script that will be great, not a KQL right now

There is no direct PowerShell command to check the available disk space for Managed Disks, but the legacy command Get-AzureDataDisk can be used for this purpose, You could check managed disk rest APi.

Currently, Azure doesn't provide direct visibility into the free space on managed disks through the Azure Portal or via the Azure Managed Disk properties. The Azure Portal shows the provisioned size but not the amount of space used or available within those disks. To check the actual disk usage (free space), you need to look from within the operating system of the VM that the disk is attached to.
Here’s a PowerShell script that will loop through all your subscriptions, list all the managed disks, and provide details like the maximum size of each disk.
# Get all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Loop through all subscriptions
foreach ($sub in $subscriptions) {
    # Set the subscription context
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $sub.Id | Out-Null

    # Print the subscription name
    Write-Output "Checking disks in subscription: $($sub.Name)"

    # Get all managed disks in the subscription
    $disks = Get-AzDisk

    # Output details of each disk
    foreach ($disk in $disks) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SubscriptionName = $sub.Name
            DiskName         = $disk.Name
            ResourceGroupName = $disk.ResourceGroupName
            DiskSizeGB       = $disk.DiskSizeGB
            DiskState        = $disk.DiskState
            OS               = $disk.OsType
            Sku              = $disk.Sku.Name
        } | Format-Table
    }
}



This script will list all managed disks across all your subscriptions, along with their sizes and other relevant information.
The DiskState property will tell you whether the disk is attached or detached.
The actual free space inside the disk is not directly accessible because Azure Managed Disks deal with block-level storage, not file system level.

To check the actual disk usage (i.e., used space within the disk), you would need to log into the operating system (for VM disks) that uses the disk and check the disk usage there, typically using tools like df in Linux or Disk Management in Windows.
Now suppose you want to fetch Disk Usage from VMs, you can try something as below-
# Fetch all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Store results
$results = @()

foreach ($sub in $subscriptions) {
    # Set context to subscription
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $sub.Id | Out-Null

    # Get all VMs in the subscription
    $vms = Get-AzVM

    foreach ($vm in $vms) {
        # Construct the script to check disk space
        $scriptBlock = {
            Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object Name, Used, Free, @{Name='TotalSize'; Expression={$_.Used + $_.Free}}
        }

        # Execute the script on the VM
        # Note: Make sure that the VM has PowerShell remoting enabled and proper network security group rules
        try {
            $diskUsage = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
            $results += $diskUsage.Value | Select-Object @{Name='VM'; Expression={$vm.Name}}, @{Name='Subscription'; Expression={$sub.Name}}, *
        } catch {
            $results += [pscustomobject]@{
                VM = $vm.Name
                Subscription = $sub.Name
                Error = "Failed to connect or execute script"
            }
        }
    }
}

# Output results
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

or you can run the following command to get all the disks in your account:
$disks = Get-AzDisk

$disks | Select-Object Name, ResourceGroupName, DiskSizeGB, @{Name="UsedSpaceGB";Expression={($_.DiskSizeGB - $_.AvailableBytes/1GB).ToString("F2")}}, @{Name="FreeSpaceGB";Expression={($_.AvailableBytes/1GB).ToString("F2")}}

References:

Tutorial: Manage disks with Azure PowerShell
Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzDisk
Select-Object

